# cordova admob plugin working but with uncaught reference error

Tags: javascript, cordova, admob, ionic-framework

My ionic/phonegap apps uses [cordova admob pro](https://github.com/floatinghotpot/cordova-admob-pro) plugin.

The `admob` working fine on real device, but i found an error when i look the chrome's `console` :

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: AdMob is not defined
```

This is my entire `admob` code :

```
var admobid = {};
if( /(android)/i.test(navigator.userAgent) ) {
    admobid = {
        banner: '',
        interstitial: ''
    };
}

if(( /(ipad|iphone|ipod|android|windows phone)/i.test(navigator.userAgent) )) {
    document.addEventListener('deviceready', initApp, false);
} else {
    initApp();
}

function initApp() {
    //Error here
    AdMob.createBanner( {
        adId: admobid.banner, 
        isTesting: false,
        overlap: false, 
        offsetTopBar: false, 
        position: AdMob.AD_POSITION.BOTTOM_CENTER//,
        //bgColor: 'yellow'
    } );

    //And here
    AdMob.prepareInterstitial({
        adId: admobid.interstitial,
        autoShow: true  //kalo mau bisa false, nanti panggil manual
    });
}
```

The error goes to `AdMob.createBanner` and `AdMob.prepareInterstitial`.

Is this error safe if i leave it to be? (because the `admob` is working fine)

Is there any way to get rid this error?

Thanks a lot for your help

Answer (score 4):

You will got this error message if you not run the app in mobile environment.

```
 Uncaught ReferenceError: AdMob is not defined
```

**`admob`** is a cordova plugin.So it will shows a error in chrome's console.
In order to avoid this error.do like this

```
if(window.cordova) {
    var admobid = {};
    if (/(android)/i.test(navigator.userAgent)) {
        admobid = {
            banner: '',
            interstitial: ''
        };
    }

    if ((/(ipad|iphone|ipod|android|windows phone)/i.test(navigator.userAgent))) {
        document.addEventListener('deviceready', initApp, false);
    } else {
        initApp();
    }

    function initApp() {
        //Error here
        AdMob.createBanner({
            adId: admobid.banner,
            isTesting: false,
            overlap: false,
            offsetTopBar: false,
            position: AdMob.AD_POSITION.BOTTOM_CENTER //,
                //bgColor: 'yellow'
        });

        //And here
        AdMob.prepareInterstitial({
            adId: admobid.interstitial,
            autoShow: true //kalo mau bisa false, nanti panggil manual
        });
    }

}
```

Thanks

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help. I will try your code and let you know

Comment: Hi, I am using Cordova with Angular. When I try to use this plugin I get the same error in my mobile device too.

Answer (score 1):

Simplest thing I did to get this working is to get the code from [this file](https://github.com/floatinghotpot/cordova-admob-pro/blob/master/test/admob_simple.js) from official wiki and paste into a new file say `admob.js`; include `admob.js` into index.html and voilà.

```
var admobid = {};

// TODO: replace the following ad units with your own
if( /(android)/i.test(navigator.userAgent) ) { 
  admobid = { // for Android
    banner: 'ca-app-pub-7545761285767751/5125248421',
    interstitial: 'ca-app-pub-7545761285767751/8299040824'
  };
} else if(/(ipod|iphone|ipad)/i.test(navigator.userAgent)) {
  admobid = { // for iOS
    banner: 'ca-app-pub-7545761285767751/3766266425',
    interstitial: 'ca-app-pub-7545761285767751/9775774020'
  };
} else {
  admobid = { // for Windows Phone
    banner: 'ca-app-pub-7545761285767751/5205973626',
    interstitial: 'ca-app-pub-7545761285767751/6682706829'
  };
}

function initApp() {
  if (! AdMob ) { alert( 'admob plugin not ready' ); return; }

  // this will create a banner on startup
  AdMob.createBanner( {
    adId: admobid.banner,
    position: AdMob.AD_POSITION.BOTTOM_CENTER,
    isTesting: true, // TODO: remove this line when release
    overlap: false,
    offsetTopBar: false,
    bgColor: 'black'
  } );

  // this will load a full screen ad on startup
  AdMob.prepareInterstitial({
    adId: admobid.interstitial,
    isTesting: true, // TODO: remove this line when release
    autoShow: true
  });
}

if(( /(ipad|iphone|ipod|android|windows phone)/i.test(navigator.userAgent) )) {
    document.addEventListener('deviceready', initApp, false);
} else {
    initApp();
}
```

Since `AdMob` is NOT defined in a browser but will work fine with emulators or real devices, please test accordingly.